# What makes RTOS behaviour predictable ?

Tags: rtos

How can you ensure that interrupt latency will not exceed a certain value when there may be other variables and factors involved, like the hardware ?

Comment: The title asks one thing, the body asks another.  Interrupt latency is not specifically related to RTOS behaviour, and is largely independent of it.  So it is not at all clear what you are asking.  Appears to be two separate questions.  I'd give an answer, but I don't know which question to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware latency is predictable. It doesn't have to be constant, but it definitely is bounded - for example interrupt entry is usually 12 cycles, but sometimes it may take 15 cycles.

RTOS latency is predictable. It also is not constant, but for example you can be certain, that the RTOS does not block the interrupts for longer than 1000 cycles at any time. Usually it will block them for much shorter periods of time, but never longer than stated.

If only your application doesn't do something strange (like a `while (1);` in the thread with highest possible priority), then the latency of the whole system will be a sum of hardware latency and RTOS latency.

The important fact here is that using real-time operating system to write your application is not the only requirement for the application to also be real-time. In your application you have to ensure that the real-time constraints are not violated. The main job of RTOS is to *NOT* get in your way of doing that, so it may not introduce random/unpredictable delays.

Generally the most important of the "predictable" things in RTOS is that the highest priority thread that is not blocked is executing. Period. In a GPOS (like the one on your desktop computer, in tablets or in smartphones), this is not true, because the scheduler actively prevents low priority threads from starvation, by allowing them to run for some time, even if there are more important things to do right now. This makes the behaviour of the application unpredictable, because one day it may react within 10us, while on the other day it may react within 10s, because the scheduler decided it's a great moment to save the logs to hard drive or maybe do some garbage collection.

Alternatively you can think that for RTOS the latency is in the range of microseconds, maybe single milliseconds. For a GPOS the max latency would probably be something like dozens of seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

"In your application you have to ensure that the real-time constraints are not violated" what are these constraints ? Can you give an example to push the point across to me ??

Comment: @FebinSunny - if your application requires a latency od 1ms, then you can violate that constraint if you put critical zones (by either disabling the interrupts or pausing the scheduler) which are longer than that. You can also violate them by assigning invalid priorities to the threads (so that the most important thread does not have the highest priority). Generally you have to perform some sort of analysis (like rate-monotonic analysis) to verify that the deadlines are met. The RTOS only makes it possible.

Comment: In another words, A key measure to determine the "real timeness" of an RTOS is variability of the the periodicity of a cycle to complete. This is generally called jitter. Higher the jitter lower is the deterministic nature of the RTOS.